# error en mi algoritmo de dijkstra compilación

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Hola estoy tratando de compilar un ejemplo Dijkstra del camino más corto al ejecutar el código no me compila muestro los errores y comparto código:

```
prog.cpp:2:15: error: too many decimal points in number
 Definir grafo[1..n][1..n], distancia[1..n], visitado[1..n] Como entero
               ^~~~
prog.cpp:2:21: error: too many decimal points in number
 Definir grafo[1..n][1..n], distancia[1..n], visitado[1..n] Como entero
                     ^~~~
prog.cpp:2:38: error: too many decimal points in number
 Definir grafo[1..n][1..n], distancia[1..n], visitado[1..n] Como entero
                                      ^~~~
prog.cpp:2:54: error: too many decimal points in number
 Definir grafo[1..n][1..n], distancia[1..n], visitado[1..n] Como entero
                                                      ^~~~
prog.cpp:1:1: error: ‘proceso’ does not name a type
 proceso Dijkstra
```

```
proceso Dijkstra
Definir grafo[1..n][1..n], distancia[1..n], visitado[1..n] Como entero
Definir infinito Como entero
Definir inicio, destino, minimo, siguiente Como entero

// Inicializar todas las distancias a infinito y todos los nodos como no visitados
Para i = 1 Hasta n Hacer
    distancia[i] = infinito
    visitado[i] = 0
FinPara

// La distancia del nodo de inicio a sí mismo es 0
distancia[inicio] = 0

// Algoritmo de Dijkstra
Para i = 1 Hasta n Hacer
    minimo = infinito
    Para j = 1 Hasta n Hacer
        Si visitado[j] = 0 Y distancia[j] < minimo Entonces
            minimo = distancia[j]
            siguiente = j
        FinSi
    FinPara
    visitado[siguiente] = 1
    Para k = 1 Hasta n Hacer
        Si distancia[siguiente] + grafo[siguiente][k] < distancia[k] Entonces
            distancia[k] = distancia[siguiente] + grafo[siguiente][k]
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinPara
FinProceso
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. El código evidentemente no es ni c#, ni java ni c++, que son las etiquetas que habías puesto originalmente. Dejé la etiqueta pseudo-código, pues no es ningún lenguaje que yo reconozca (sobre todo por las palabras  reservadas en español). Sugiero que agregues las etiquetas del lenguaje específico que utilizas para encontrar la ayuda que buscas.  Por otro lado `.cpp` es una extensión que se utiliza con c++. Usa la extensión que identifique los archivos de tu lenguaje, para evitar confusiones. Detalles que no son importantes para las máquinas, pero si para los humanos.

Comment: Finalmente, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

los arreglos se declaran con la palabra **DIMENSION** separando (en el caso de los bi-dimensionales), las filas de las columnas con una coma, de la siguiente manera:

```
DIMENSION grafo[ 6, 10 ], distancia[ 4 ], visitado[ 3 ]
```

Puedes reemplazar los valores numéricos por "n" si lo deseas.
La asignación se realiza con "<-", por lo que la otra linea conflictiva, quedaría así:

```
Si distancia[ siguiente ] + grafo[ siguiente, k ] < distancia[ k ] Entonces
    distancia[ k ] <- distancia[ siguiente ] + grafo[ siguiente, k ]
```